# Why does CrudRepository make a seperate request to resolve foreign key objects?

Tags: java, sql

Lets say i have two entities:

EntityOne:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class EntityOne {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private LocalDate date;

  @ManyToOne
  private EntityTwo entityTwo;
}
```

EntityTwo:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class EntityTwo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String name;
}
```

If i used the default `entityOneRepository.findAll()` method from `CrudRepository` i would get a `List<EntityOne>`. But instead of just doing one SQL request, theres actually one request to get all `EntityOne` objects and then theres another SQL request for **each** `EntityOne` to resolve its `entityTwo` attribute which is a `@ManyToOne` relation. So theres 1 + n query requests if n is the number of `EntityOne` objects in the database. Why is that the default behaviour? Its possible to get all this done in just one request without having to send another seperate request for each object just to resolve its `ManyToOne` attribute.

You could for example define a method:

```
@Query("SELECT new packagePath.EntityOne(entityOne.id, entityOne.date, 
        entityOne.entityTwo.id, entityOne.entityTwo.name) 
        FROM EntityOne entityOne"
List<EntityOne> findAllInOneRequest();
```

and then have a constructor:

```
public Entityone(long id, LocalDate date, long entityTwoId, String entityTwoName) {
  this.id = id; 
  this.date = date;
  this.entityTwo = new EntityTwo(entityTwoId, entityTwoname)
}
```

That way im able to find all `EntityOne` objects with their `entityTwo` attribute in just one request instead of having to do a seperate request to resolve `entityTwo` for each object which saves a lot of time, because of the roundtriptime to the database. Why isnt this the default behaviour? Whats the advantage of doing a seperate request?

Comment: Try to use `join fetch` to connect your entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that. FETCH JOIN is a common way to resolve N+1 problem for joining records.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM EntityOne entityOne JOIN FETCH entityOne.entityTwo"
List<EntityOne> findAllInOneRequest();
```

Comment: Like i said, the code i wrote is working for me, i was just wondering why the default behavior of `findAll()` - if i dont write any query myself - leads to N+1 requests. Why doesnt it automatically use `JOIN FETCH` to resolve the N+1 problem. Why do we have to write that query manually ?